# Highcharts donut chart is not accessible with screen readers

Tags: highcharts, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

I am trying to add accessibility to an donut chart created using Highcharts.

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Donut highcahrt with accessibility</title>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <figure>
    <div id="chart-container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">Chart showing how 2020 has seen a massive growth in sales compared to 2019 and 2018. hahahaha!!!</p>      
  </figure>
</body>
</html>
```

JS code

```
// Create the chart
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart-container',
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            shadow: false
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' %';
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Browsers',
        data: [["Firefox",6],["MSIE",4]],
        size: '20%',
        innerSize: '85%',color:['red','red'],
        showInLegend:true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
});
```

The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suraseprasad/eoLpqgdt/).

When I use NVDA with Firefox(version 83) on Windows 7, the screen reader doesn't read the description specified in the HTML as specified in the documentation(https://www.highcharts.com/docs/accessibility/accessibility-module). Same is the case for JAWS on IE.

Comment: Could you turn this into a fiddle please? I can't see if there is a reason this wouldn't work but need to see the output to be able to help.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie https://jsfiddle.net/suraseprasad/eoLpqgdt/

Comment: It works for me, are you reading far enough, the `highcharts-description` gets read after the title etc. Or am I misunderstanding the issue (that the HTML info you added isn't being read is how I understood the question)?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie weird. NVDA( version 2020.3) with FF(83) on Windows 7 all of which is running in Virtual Box is the setup. NVDA doesn't read the description. Same for IE with JAWS.

Comment: What exactly are you experiencing as I just left it in read mode once the item was selected, does it read other stuff such as the title?

Comment: @prasad.surase Everything works fine with your chart on our device. It works well with VoiceOver. NVDA has had some issues with SVG, please try to test this chart: https://www.highcharts.com/samples/highcharts/accessibility/accessible-pie and let me know if work correctly.